# which takes precedence: mldivide or dot product(or neither)?

Tags: matrices, operator-theory

Let's say I have a function like the following:
$$ERM^T\backslash(M\backslash(R^Tc))$$
I will first dot $(R^Tc)$ and then compute $M\backslash(R^Tc)$.
Let's say $X = M\backslash(R^Tc)$.
Then comes the part I am confused about: is it

1. $E(R(M^T\backslash X))$
2. $E((RM^T)\backslash X)$
3. $(ERM^T)\backslash X$

or are they all the same which I am skeptical about.

(by the way, what are appropriate tags for this kind of question?)

Comment: This is just bad notation. Any self respecting mathematician (or indeed anyone who uses mathematics a lot) will always clarify this. If you're talking about how mathlab handles it, you should just run some experiments to see.

Comment: Parenthesis always first. You should always be careful enough when writing the code to ensure with parentheses to get things in the order you want them. So in $ERM^T$ insert parentheses as you want it to be calculated.